# Evaluating function objects from within a function in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

Lets say we have two defined function objects

```
add1 = lambda x: x+1
```

and

```
square = lambda x: x*x
```

now I want to have a function that calls and adds the result of these two functions.
What I thought would work is:

```
def addFuncs(f,g):
    f+g

addFuncs(add1,square)(10)
```

Which I thought would give me an answer of 111 (10*10 + 10+1)
But that just gave me an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'`
So I tried:

```
def addFunctions(f, g):
    def getf():
        return f
    def getg():
        return g
    return getf() + getg()
```

But still to no avail...
However, if I do

```
def addFunctions(f, g):
    return f
```

it pops out with 100, so it seems to evaluate the function on return, But I can't figure out how to get it to evaluate the functions first and then operate on them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT
Got it!

```
def addFunctions(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(x) + g(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def addFuncs(f,g):
    return lambda x: f(x) + g(x)

addFuncs(add1,square)(10)
```

Python doesn't support adding functions together which both of your attempts tried to do. Instead, you need to create a new function, such as with lambda which calls the original functions.

Comment: Thanks Winston,  
This was spot on!

Answer (score 1):

Your original idea will work if you instead call these functions and then add their return values, rather than trying to add them themselves;

```
def addFuncs(f,g,x):
    f(x) + g(x)
```

This is because **f** and **g** are actually [LambdaTypes](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html?highlight=lambda#types.LambdaType), and the () operator calls them, allowing the + operator to add their return values.  When you use the + operator on them directly, the + operator doesn't know how to add two LambdaTypes.

**EDIT**
To add a little more; the reason

```
def addFunctions(f, g):
    def getf():
        return f
    def getg():
        return g
    return getf() + getg()
```

doesn't work is because you are, again, trying to add together two function objects.  However, your example of

```
def addFunctions(f, g):
    return f
```

WILL work, because this will simply return another function object, which is then called with an argument of value 10 in your statement

```
addFuncs(add1,square)(10)
```

Comment: Thanks staticfloat,
Unfortunately that gave me the error `TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` but your telling me it was a Lambda type gave me the idea `return lambda x: f(x) + g(x)` which works!

Comment: Yeap, looks like you might have missed my edit to include the "x" parameter in addFuncs, but Winston's answer is awesome because it creates a new lambda to pass the single argument into both with.  :D

Answer (score 0):

`addFuncs` takes arbitrarily many functions as input and returns a function:

```
def addFuncs(*funcs):
    def _addFuncs(*args):
        return sum(f(*args) for f in funcs)
    return _addFuncs
add1 = lambda x: x+1
square = lambda x: x*x

print(addFuncs(add1,square)(10))
```

yields

```
111
```

Comment: That's really cool! I wouldn't have thought to use list comprehension in there.